# Android Design Library 23.1.0 NavigationView

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-navigationview

I'm having an issue with design library 23.1.0

I tried to update the design library from 23.0.1 to 23.1.0,
but now my app crashes when trying to inflate my navigationView.

If I'm not mistaken, there shouldn't be any breaking changes concerning the navigationView between these 2 versions.

I've tried comparing my code with the cheesesquare project (https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)
But I can't find any real differences.

If more information is needed, I will provide it.

The crash occurs in my Activity on `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)`

My XML is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The crash log is quiet long and not complete:

```
    10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: be.myApp, PID: 10085
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.myApp/be.myApp.home.SyndicHomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at be.myApp.home.SyndicHomeActivity.onCreate(SyndicHomeActivity.java:39)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at be.myApp.home.SyndicHomeActivity.onCreate(SyndicHomeActivity.java:39) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at be.myApp.home.SyndicHomeActivity.onCreate(SyndicHomeActivity.java:39) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:165)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at be.myApp.home.SyndicHomeActivity.onCreate(SyndicHomeActivity.java:39) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:165) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at be.myApp.home.SyndicHomeActivity.onCreate(SyndicHomeActivity.java:39) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:165) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at be.myApp.home.SyndicHomeActivity.onCreate(SyndicHomeActivity.java:39) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error creating LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
10-24 20:57:47.314 10085-10085/be.myApp E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.createLayoutMan
```

**UPDATE:**

Apparently it is an issue with proguard.

I haven't found what rules are needed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution.

I had to add the following rules to my proguard file:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

NOTE: I didn't receive any warnings from proguard to indicate this problem.

Comment: You are a genius. This only happens in my debug non-proguarded builds, but I did not go that far.